# Unable to pull selectedvalue/item from dropdownlist on update

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i have a dropdownlist in a gridview that i am attempting to get selectvalues from to update my database. My problem is: is that when press the update button, it ignores what was selected for the selected value and grabs what the first value is set to when the dropdownlist was first loaded.

So my question is: is how do obtain the selected value from a dropdownlist during the update event of a gridview.

Below you will find my codebehind, and the markup for the gridview.

codebehind:

```
    /// <summary>
/// Handles the Click event of the update button under edit in the gridview control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
protected void GridViewHolder_Updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) 
{
    int machineid;
    string machineid1;
    string machineTypeid;
    string machineModelid;

    //retrieve and set the data
    GridViewHolder.EditIndex = e.RowIndex;
    BindData();

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridViewHolder.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox mID = row.FindControl("MachineIDText") as TextBox;
    DropDownList mType = row.FindControl("MachineTypeDropDown") as DropDownList;
    DropDownList mModel = row.FindControl("MachineModelDropDown") as DropDownList;

    machineid1 = mID.Text;
    machineid = Convert.ToInt32(machineid1);
    machineTypeid = mType.SelectedValue;
    machineModelid = mModel.SelectedValue;

    try
    {
        if (machineTypeid != "empty" || machineModelid != "empty")
        {
            if (machineTypeid != "empty")
            {
                inputsService.UpdateMachineTypes(machineid, machineTypeid);
            }
            if (machineModelid != "empty")
            {
                inputsService.UpdateMachineModels(machineid, machineModelid);
            }
            UpdateSucceed.Visible = true;
            logger.Debug("Updating - Database successfully updated!");
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateFail.Visible = true;
            logger.Debug("Updating - Database had no data selected to be updated.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.ErrorFormat("Updating - Failed to update the table, ex = {0}", ex);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles the Click event of the cancel button under edit in the gridview control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCancelEditEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
protected void GridViewHolder_Canceling(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    //reset the edit index
    GridViewHolder.EditIndex = -1;
    //Bind data to GridViewHolder
    BindData();
}

protected void GridViewHolder_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.GridViewHolder.EditIndex != -1)
    {
        DropDownList mType = e.Row.FindControl("MachineTypeDropDown") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList mModel = e.Row.FindControl("MachineModelDropDown") as DropDownList;
    }
}

protected void GridViewHolder_Editing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //set the edit index to a new value
    GridViewHolder.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Bind data to gridviewholder
    BindData();
}

#endregion

#region Private Methods

private void BindData()
{
    GridViewHolder.DataSource = Session["MachineTable"];
    GridViewHolder.DataBind();
}
```

gridview markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewHolder" 
                      runat="server" 
                      AllowPaging="True" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      BackColor="Transparent" 
                      BorderColor="#999999" 
                      BorderStyle="Ridge" 
                      BorderWidth="3px" 
                      CellPadding="4" 
                      CellSpacing="2" 
                      DataSourceID="MachineDataSet" 
                      ForeColor="Black" 
                      HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                      HorizontalAlign="Center"  
                      RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                      Width="796px"
                      OnRowUpdating="GridViewHolder_Updating"
                      OnRowCancelingEdit="GridViewHolder_Canceling"
                      OnRowEditing="GridViewHolder_Editing"
                      OnRowDataBound="GridViewHolder_DataBound"                          
                      EnableViewState="False">
            <RowStyle BackColor="Transparent" 
                      HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" 
                                   SortExpression="ID" 
                                   Visible="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="MachineIDLabel" 
                                   runat="server" 
                                   Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'
                                   Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="MachineIDText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteName" 
                                HeaderText="Site Name" 
                                SortExpression="SiteName"
                                ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" 
                                HeaderText="Machine Name" 
                                ReadOnly="true" 
                                SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Type" 
                                   SortExpression="MachineType">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="MachineTypeLabel" 
                                   runat="server" 
                                   Text='<%# Bind("MachineType") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>                            
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="MachineTypeDropDown" 
                                          runat="server" 
                                          AppendDataBoundItems="True"                                                
                                          Height="21px" 
                                          Width="217px" 
                                          DataSourceID="GetMachineType" 
                                          DataTextField="Name" 
                                          DataValueField="ID">
                            <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" 
                                          Text="Select a Machine Type." 
                                          Value="empty">
                            </asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Model" SortExpression="MachineModel">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="MachineModelLabel" 
                                   runat="server" 
                                   Text='<%# Bind("MachineModel") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>                            
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="MachineModelDropDown" 
                                          runat="server" 
                                          AppendDataBoundItems="True"                                                
                                          Height="21px" Width="217px" 
                                          DataSourceID="GetMachineModel" 
                                          DataTextField="Name" 
                                          DataValueField="ID">
                            <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" 
                                          Text="Select a Machine Model." 
                                          Value="empty">
                            </asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" 
                                  ShowEditButton="True"
                                  CausesValidation="false" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                               Wrap="True" />
                </asp:CommandField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="Transparent" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="Transparent" 
                        ForeColor="Black" 
                        HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Transparent" 
                              Font-Bold="True" 
                              ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" 
                         Font-Bold="True" 
                         ForeColor="White" 
                         HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     </asp:GridView>
```

any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: You have viewstate turned off in your gridview, does it make a difference if you turn it on?

Comment: @ipr101 when i have viewstate turnned on it throws, a failed to load viewstate when attempting to run either the cancel or update buttons in edit mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [RowUpdating event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) has event-arguments of type `GridViewUpdateEventArgs`. This has dictionaries for key-, old- and new-values. There is no need to get them by using FindControl on the GridViewRow.

But the main reason why you are getting the old values is the fact that you are DataBinding it again in this event. Then you're overwriting all changes with the values from your DataSource.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx

**Update**: it seems that the `DropDownList`'s `SelectedValue` is not part of the `NewValues` dictionary. Therefore you could add it in the `RowUpdating` event.

```
protected void GridViewHolder_Updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) 
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridViewHolder.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DropDownList mType = row.FindControl("MachineTypeDropDown") as DropDownList;
    e.NewValues.Add("MachineType", mType.SelectedValue):
}
```

Comment: okay, but if i remove the databinding form the updating event i end up being unable to find the dropdownlist as a control. How would i go about finding the ddl in update without running the databind in the update?

Comment: You should DataBind the GridView **after** you've read the new values. See this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx

Comment: Okay, but my problem is: is without that databind before searching for the controls the page in unable to find any of the controls thus throwing a null reference error and being unable to read any values let alone the new values.

Comment: Old and New value dictionaries will not contain the values selected in the DropDownList box though.

Comment: @Tim, thanks your contributions are usually dead on, I was a bit surprised until reading the edit. thanks and great work!!!